# Advice on hosting Razor Components in Docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Razor Components project, using the ASP.NET Core 3.0 Preview2 release from 29 Jan. I will need to host this in a (Linux) Docker container. Has anybody managed to get this working please?

Answer (score 0):

So what is the question? Microsoft has made available `docker` images for `asp .net core 3.0` already, just pull the image and enjoy. Example of tag: `3.0.100-preview2-sdk-stretch`

Complete list is available at:
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/TAGS.md

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, however I don't see Razor Components there, and when I start a new RC project in VS2019, the docker support checkbox is greyed out (picture below). So I'm wondering if anybody has managed to do this for themselves and if so would they be able to explain the methodology.

Thanks!

[image]